# Simple Calculator python Sololearn

Tags: python

I am to write a program by taking two integers as input and output their sum on Sololearn using python
But I don’t seem to get what they want me to do

Comment: Daniel, check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show us your code (see [mcve]).

Comment: We are on stack overflow, share your code and your doubts

Answer (score 1):

```
num1 = int(input('Enter your first number: '))
num2 = int(input('Enter your second number: '))
print('Your sum is', num1 + num2)
```

I would suggest doing more research on the `input` function in python. Also, in the future, please provide the code that you have already written so that it is easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am to write a program by **taking two integers as input** and **output their sum** on Sololearn using python But I don’t seem to get what they want me to do

This is what the lesson is asking you to do.

- Step 1: Take two integers as input
- Step 2: Output their sum (addition)

Step 1 Using the `input()` function wrapped in the `int()` type allows a user to input a number from the command line.

```
num1 = int(input('Enter the 1st number: '))
num2 = int(input('Enter the 2nd number: '))
```

Step 2 Add the two entered numbers using the '+' operand

```
sum_of_two_numbers = num1 + num2
print('The sum of two numbers is', sum_of_two_numbers)
```

I suggest wrapping the code in a `try-and-catch` block.

```
import traceback, os 
try:
    num1 = int(input('Enter the 1st number: '))
    num2 = int(input('Enter the 2nd number: '))

    sum_of_two_numbers = num1 + num2
    print('The sum of two numbers is', sum_of_two_numbers)

except Exception as ex:
          
    template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:{1!r}"
    message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
    print( message )

    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: I think with the try-except block you are making this to complicated for @Daniel

Comment: It is not too complicated when one requires only copying and pasting a code.

Comment: Yes but he also needs to understand it

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```py
a = int(input("A: ")) # Convert input string to int
b = int(input("B: "))
print("A + B =", a+b)
```